# How to save Token to Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, ajax, access-token

I'm working on a login system for an app in school. I can register a user that gets saved to my azure documentDB. I can then, sort of log in with the user. But it (the Token) never gets saved so that I can access the token...

The script for the log in looks like this:

```
      var signin = function() {

            var tokenUrl = "http://localhost:15746/Token";
            var loginData = $("#userSignup").serialize();
            loginData = loginData + "&grant_type=password";
            $.post(tokenUrl, loginData).then(navigateToEvent);
                                                      
            return false;
        }

        $("#signup").click(signin);
```

How could I store the Token? In Local Storage? How?

Answer (score 41):

To save a string in Local Storage you use

```
window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

You can get the value later with:

```
window.localStorage.getItem(key);
```

Comment: I've tried something similar. I dont really know (or understand), what to put as the value..! I do know that the access_token should be there..

Comment: If you need to store the access token you can use `window.localStorage.setItem('access_token', token)` and then when you want to retrieve it: `window.localStorage.getItem('access_token')`.

Comment: So:

$.post(tokenUrl, loginData).then(navigateToEvent); and then :
window.localStorage.setItem('access_token', token);?

Comment: When I put the setItem code under the post method and run the 'show'.. I go to the console window in debug mode and write the getItem code you've presented. The console only returns 'undifined'.. Do I need to parse and stuff? Shouldn't it be like:

window.localStorage.setItem('access_token', tokenUrl.token)? So it knows where to find the token?

Comment: is it safe to have the token in the local storage ? Is there anyway that we can pass the token to a directed page?

Answer (score 6):

Dont save a Token in the Local Storage. Its not a good Style because you open up to attackers. I found this link on my search: https://medium.com/@benjamin.botto/secure-access-token-storage-with-single-page-applications-part-1-9536b0021321.

This is a part from whats inside the page:

“It’s recommended not to store any sensitive information in local storage.” -OWASP Cheat Sheet

“Don’t store tokens in local storage.” -Auth0: Where to Store Tokens

“You are safe from CSRF, but you have opened yourself up to a much greater attack vector… XSS.” Okta: JWTs Suck

“Don’t store [JWTs] in local storage (or session storage).” LogRocket: JWT Authentication Best Practices

“It is best to avoid letting the JavaScript code ever see the access token.” OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps: Best Current Practice

Comment: Why do using tokens in JS like this suck? What will a hacker do, log into his own account?? Services such as Google tend to lock accounts to certain domains and they are hard to spoof when protected by HTTPS, right?

Comment: if the web app is not for the public and exclusive only for some private clients, I know the best thing to do there is by putting great security in the back-end.

- white listing
- multi factor auth